# Hardcoded Web API calls in code versus multiple environments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Actually, I hardcode my Web API calls like this :

```
$http.get('my/production/web/api/method');
```

If I want to switch to a test environment, which is another Web API, I don't want to manually change every hardcoded call in the code.

Is there a way to solve this by using a configuration file or has angularjs a feature to handle that ?

Comment: You answered your own question. Just don't hardcode it, use config files, which can be simple JS objects with custom properties, and change those files when using in different env.

Comment: If the domain is same, use relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like domakas said, use your own config file:

```
var config={
   environment:'production'
   //environment:'dev'
};

$http.get('my/'+config.environment+'/web/api/method');
```

Make your own function:

```
function queryWebApi(method) {
    $http.get('my/'+config.environment+'/web/api/'+method);
}
```